# How to find out which Node.js packages to update after updating one of them?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I am developing an application that consists of several Node.js packages. Of course, they aren't relied on only by the application itself, but some of the packages provide so essentially basic things, that they are also required by other packages (think logging, e.g.).

Now, if I update a package, I have to update all the other packages' `package.json` files to make sure that I consistently use the new version everywhere. Unfortunately, this results in a (recursive) loop. And of course, the order in which I update the packages is important because I only want to touch each package once, not multiple times.

How do I figure out, once I made a change, what packages to update, and in which order?

Currently, I am using two custom-developed small tools called [reqd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reqd) and [forany](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forany) to at least find out which other packages rely on an updated one, but this is only the first step in a number of steps.

How could I solve this?